# Making a Platform game with Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, platform, side-scroller

I'm trying to develop a platform game similar to Geometry Dash but i'm facing a lot of problems during the making of the algorithm.

I don't barely know how to proceed. Are the levels structured with a long image ( that is the ground) with obstacles added, or there are many obstacles generated progressively during the game? 
I'd like to know where to start from, what to draw and how to place it in my game, how to build the collision detection.

The game will be an auto-scrolling platformer, so, will the character's asset be moving right or will all the level except for the character be moving left?

I'm a beginner, so i would like to receive detailed answers and not too difficult to understand. Thank you.

if you have any advice I would gladly listen to it.

Comment: First, you need to learn game development by following different tutorials or books. Then, you can ask specific questions on Stackoverflow. This question is too broad.

Comment: I recommended you something simpler like [Chapter 1 — Creating an App](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/programming/01/index.html) :)

Comment: I've done all corona tutorials but they doesn't explain how to do a platformer.

Answer (score 0):

> I've done all corona tutorials but they doesn't explain how to do a platformer.  - Luca Pasini

Looks like you still don't **feel** how game work from inside. Tutorials probably will not help you much. I think you need to start something very simple by your own - not by tutorials.

For example:

- Show red rectangle
- Show blue recatngle
- Tap on the screen and red rectangle must change his position (not by transitions - just by core x,y change)
- If they are collide - show text: "You win". Collision check just by raw calculations.

Then go with updates, that will make it looks more like a game.